# Nginx: select a vhost or return a redirect based on the chosen TLS cipher and/or version

Tags: nginx, ssl

Is it possible to use a different vhost, or redirect the user, in response to them using old TLS ciphers or a certain TLS version? I can't find a relevant configuration option but I might be overlooking it.

I found [this question about per-vhost cipher configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/669501/define-ssl-ciphers-in-nginx-for-each-vhost) but that would require allowing all ciphers on the main domain and doing some javascript magic to attempt, and detect failure for, a redirect to a more restricted subdomain.

Another question asks [whether a redirect can be returned upon cipher negotiation failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/591188/redirect-browser-based-on-non-negotiable-ssl-tls-protocol-or-cipher) (and also dives into a theoretical question of including some fallback mechanism in a future TLS version), which is different because then the failure already happened and the browser will be showing the user a TLS error. What I am looking for is letting the negotiation succeed (within reason) and then using the cipher/version that was selected to make a decision about which page to show.

An alternative solution might be to use different server software: another web server, some proxy module, an interactive language like PHP where I can script this check... Any solution that works, works, but something that natively works with Nginx and static page hosting is preferred.

Comment: Just an idea is to allow old ciphers but check [$ssl_cipher](https://nginx.org/r/$ssl_cipher) variable and redirect if it's an old cipher. Didn't check.

Comment: You will not get an A+ on ssllabs check though.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thanks for the hint, that looks promising!